# how to access a thread from EventQueue in java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-handling, applet

Hi am running an applet code processing from `EventQueue` as below

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        plotApplet();
    }
});
```

Hear from `plotApplet()` processing of the applet component setup is done. Now I want to get access to the thread which is running this `Runnable` class. I need this as there is a need, where I will have to stop this thread explicitly when user send next request for process, so I just want to stop this previous thread which may take very much time, I then immediatly start the new thread.

So please tell me how can I get reference to the thread running by `EventQueue`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use this EventQueue for long running tasks.  If you do so, your GUI will lock up and you won't be able to stop it until it it has stopped which isn't very useful.

If you have a long running task you should start your own thread, e.g. a ExecutorService which you can issue tasks which you can call `Future.cancel(true)` to ask it to stop

Comment: But sun recommend to run swing from EventQueue, and also If I use another way to run the thread then my GUI does not plot correctly

Comment: You correct that the displaying must be done by the Event thread, however while you are doing this, your event thread is not doing anything else. i.e. the GUI will stop doing anything.  A way around this is to break your task, into many small tasks which take less than say 0.1 seconds. e.g. your task can do some work and then start another task which will do the same.  This way your GUI will not lock up for long.